# Navigation app is on filesystem, but cant find it on Android

Tags: applications, data-recovery, navigation

I have an Android navigation Navon Platinum Explorer with Adroid 4.0.

I reseted it to factory settings, and the navigation software, iGo Primo, disappeared from the list of applications.

However it is still on the filesystem.

How can I "recover" the application, so Android will see it?
I cant just reinstall it because of specific license files.

Comment: Which navigation app is causing you problems, Navon or iGo?

Comment: iGO Primo software

Answer (score 0):

I backed up the filesystem to my computer and then downloaded and installed the original iGo Primo .apk file.

That did solve the issue.